# Libcurl returns timeout error when used from multiple threads, but not from a single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

I'm using `libcurl` with C++. I have made a thread-safe class for downloading webpages. Each call to static `download` method creates "easy" handle, performs the job and frees the handle. When I use it from the single thread - everything's fine. But when I spawn several threads to download several pages in parallel I sometimes (not fro every download, but quite often) get error saying "timeout". I have a reasonably high timeout configured (5 sec connection timeout and 25 sec global timeout).

Any ideas as to what might be the cause and how to fix it?

P. S. It happens on both Windows and Linux.

Here's the code of the method in question:

```
void CHttpDownloaderLibcurl::downloaderThread( const CUrl& url, CThreadSafeQueue<CHtmlPage>& q)
{
    CHtmlPage page (url);

    CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();

    if (!handle)
    {
        assert(handle);
        return;
    }

    int curlErr = setCurlOptions(handle, url, (void*)onCurlDownloadCallback, (void*)&page.byteArray());
    if (CURLE_OK != curlErr)
    {
        assert("Error setting options" == (char*)curlErr);
        return;
    }

    curlErr = curl_easy_perform(handle);

    page._info = getInfo(handle);

    curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
    if (CURLE_OK != curlErr)
    {
        if (curlErr == CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT)
        {
            CLogger() << "Curl timeout!";
        }
        else
            CLogger() << url.urlString() << ": Error performing download = " << curlErr;
        return;
    }

    q.push(page);
}
```

Comment: You say each thread call a static `download` method and this method create a `easy` handle. Can you paste the `download` code? Are those threads share one `easy` handle?

Comment: @Louis: Of course they don't share handles! In fact, they share nothing at all.

Comment: The _curl_easy*_ functions are not intended for use in threaded applications. Using them there may cause intermittent errors.

Comment: @Amazed: libcurl documenation clearly states that all curl_easy functions are thread-safe as long as threads don't share handles. In fact, there is an example of multithreading with easy functions: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html